# Overriding a conditional format with another if condition holds

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Currently my data are percentages, and it has a conditional format that just formats it using data bars:
[image]

I would like the sheet to omit all percentages if the value in column I
is less than 150, so the second row would be blank, so it looks something like this:
[image]

I was thinking of adding another conditional format on I
that just makes the cells have white text and white fill,
but it doesn't get rid of the data bars and ends up looking like this:
[image]

Is there an easy solution to this? any ways other than conditional formatting is fine, I just want to keep the original data bars if the value in I is at least 150, but remove them and the percentage if that value is less than 150. Going through the entire workbook and adding in an IF statement will take a lot of time so I prefer not to do this.

Comment: More detail, more information, is needed here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Don't vandalize your own question!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you’re doing something like this:

[image: conditional formatting with white text for “I” value < 150]

You need to check the “Stop If True” box:

[image: same as above but with “Stop If True” checked]

to get Excel to stop processing the conditional format rules
when the `In` value is less than 150.

Result:

[image: Spreadsheet with blank cells in second row, as desired]